# Jquery only grabbing the first id for a list of items

Tags: jquery, html, click

I'm working on turning divs into links using jquery. To make the links work I need to get back both the story_id and chapter_id of each chapter, but when I do I only get back the first chapter_id...so all the links are the same. Am I making scene?

My jquery looks like this for a story block.

```
$('.storyInnerBlock').click(function(){
  var story_id = $('.story_id').val();
  var chapter_id = $('.chapter_id').val();
  $ (location). attr ('href', 'http://www.writeyourfiction.com/index.php/story/readStory/'+story_id+'/'+chapter_id);
});
```

I set up a fiddle to kind of show whats going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/zazvorniki/vwnCb/6/

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Your linked demo bears no resemblance to the problem you describe; alerting `"this"` tells us nothing.

Comment: sorry, my last save didn't go through. Just fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.storyInnerBlock').click(function () {
    var context = $(this).closest('.storyInnerBlock'),
        story_id = context.find('.story_id').val(),
        chapter_id = context.find('.chapter_id').val();

    alert('story ' + story_id);
    alert('chapter ' + chapter_id);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vwnCb/7/).

Effectively this is because the getter methods (those methods that return the value, text or HTML (among others)) return the content of only the *first* element of the matched set returned by the selector.

The above approach supplies a context, finding the closest ancestor `.storyInnerBlock` element and restricting the search, with `find()`, within that element.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

val() only returns the value of the first element in the matched set, so story_id and chapter_ id are the same for all your links.  <strike>You need to step through each match in a loop.</strike> Actually, you just need to use $(this) inside your click() function to refer to the current element in the matched set because the click() function does an implicit loop over the matched set:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $('.storyInnerBlock').on('click', function(){
    var story_id = $(this).children('.story_id').val()
    var chapter_id = $(this).children('.chapter_id').val()
    console.log(story_id + "<--->" + chapter_id);
  });

});
```

Comment: So, just to be clear I need to put a loop in my click? Do I loop through each div or something else?

Comment: @zazvorniki, I posted an example.

Comment: Thank you for posting that! I used the above answer as it seemed to fit a little more with the rest of my code. :)